# How can I "tell" CMake 3.9+ I want to use NVIDIA's OpenCL library?

Tags: cmake, build, cuda, opencl

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
# ... etc etc ...
find_package(CUDA 8.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
```

and this finds CUDA and OpenCL. But - it prefers my system's non-NVIDIA OpenCL library over the library which comes with the CUDA installation. Actually, it's worse than that, since I get:

```
//Path to a file.
OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include

//Path to a library.
OpenCL_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so
```

in my `CMakeCache.txt` file.

How can I, from within CMakeLists.txt (i.e. not as the user but as the package maintainer), get CMake to switch the order of preference?

Note: Yes, it needs to be CMake 3.9 for compatibility reasons.

Comment: "Yes, it needs to be CMake 3.9 for compatibility reasons." - we used to say that too, until the maintenance pain of reimplementing behaviors that have long been in upstream became too great. Now we're running CMake 3.20 on ancient ARM SOCs. This is a decision, not a requirement

Comment: @AlexReinking: When you develop a library, targeting a wide audience, you can't decide what version of CMake people will have...

Comment: The CMake snap on Ubuntu 18.04+ is always up to date and automatically updates itself. Ubuntu 20.04 has 3.16 in the repository and Kitware provides an APT repo for 18.04+ that is always current. Homebrew is always up to date. VS2019 updates frequently and is on 3.19 now. The binary releases for all may be trivially installed without admin/root, including aarch64. Who are your users - presumably C++ developers - who refuse to update an essential tool?

Comment: Presumably your users will have to install CUDA on their systems to build your library. While they're waiting for CUDA to download, they can install CMake

Comment: @AlexReinking: Well, CUDA is not a "requirement" in the sense that people will only care about this library if they have CUDA installed. Installing CMake is quite the requirement, and building and installing it are not even trivial. I realize life is much nicer with a newer CMake version, but I just can't go there. Even requiring CMake 3.9 is a bit of stretch: It was released merely 3 years ago...

Comment: "Installing Cmake is quite the requirement and building and installing it are not even trivial." -- the Linux binaries may be untarred and run out of the directory as a normal user. You cannot possibly have a more trivial installation than that.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Are you saying there are fully-statically-linked CMake binaries available? Which don't rely on absolutely anytinhg?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232737/discussion-between-alex-reinking-and-einpoklum).

Comment: @AlexReinking: Well, apparently, you're right!

Comment: I'm happy the binaries worked for you! I hope you get to upgrade and spare yourself this sort of pain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on CMake 3.9, your hands are very much tied.

---

If you were using CMake 3.17+ then you shouldn't find `OpenCL` at all. You would just use `FindCUDAToolkit` and the `CUDA::OpenCL` target:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

find_package(CUDAToolkit 8.0 REQUIRED)

add_executable(my_target ...)
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE CUDA::OpenCL)
```

---

If you were using CMake 3.16, then you could still use `FindCUDA` and link to the CUDA-found OpenCL using the package variables:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test)

find_package(CUDA 8.0 REQUIRED)

cuda_add_executable(my_target ...)
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE ${CUDA_OpenCL_LIBRARY})
```

---

If you were as far back as 3.12, then you could use the `<Pkg>_ROOT` variable to guide the search:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test)

find_package(CUDA 8.0 REQUIRED)

set(OpenCL_ROOT "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}")
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
```

and I would expect that to find the right OpenCL version.

---

But on earlier versions, the best you can do is use the CUDA root variable to find OpenCL inside the CUDA installation manually. Then, let `FindOpenCL` create the imported target:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(test)

find_package(CUDA 8.0 REQUIRED)

find_path(
  OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR CL/opencl.h
  HINTS "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/include"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
  set(opencl_lib64 "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/lib64" )
endif()

find_library(
  OpenCL_LIBRARY OpenCL
  HINTS ${opencl_lib64} "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/lib"
  PATH_SUFFIXES "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)

cuda_add_executable(my_target ...)
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE OpenCL::OpenCL)
```

Comment: So, the `find_path()` and `find_library()` will bias the behavior the `find_package()` call?

Comment: @einpoklum that's right. Those find calls set the two cache variables FindOpenCL uses: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindOpenCL.html